# Adding AFP protocol to Windows Server shares

Tags: macos, windows-server-2008, afp

Is there a way to add the Apple File Protocol (AFP) to Windows Server for shares, currently Windows uses SMB but the transfer rate to OSX clients is ridiculously slow, I am currently running an Ubuntu server box with AFP but would like to know if there is an option or way to get it working on Windows Server (2008 R2).

Comment: Interestingly, the next release of OS X is [switching to smb2](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588593-263/os-x-mavericks-switches-to-smb2-networking/) instead of AFP for sharing between Macs.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft used to include [Services for Macintosh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736837(v=ws.10).aspx), but it's no longer supported in Server 2008, so you'll have to go for a third party solution.

There's no Windows port of netatalk, but you could of course run it virtualized. Otherwise, the only options appear to be the commercial products [MacServerIP](http://www.cyansoftware.com/MacServerIP.htm) and [ExtremeZ-IP](http://www.grouplogic.com/enterprise-file-sharing/mac-windows-file-sharing/). Unfortunately ExtremeZ-IP is quite expensive, at $795 for a 3 client license. MacServerIP has no listed price that I could find, which suggest it's also priced rather highly.